# Can't bind to 'ngForIndex' since it isn't a known property of 'div'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm getting the error:

NG0303: Can't bind to 'ngForIndex' since it isn't a known property of 'div'.

on my angular application, can't find anything that talks about ngForIndex, and it seems like my way of indexing should be correct based on what I've seen and my experience in the past using ngFor.

```html
<div class="grid-container">
    <div id="projects" class="projects">
        <h1>Projects</h1>
        <div class="row" style="margin: 0;">
            <div class="col-4" *ngFor="let project of projectList; let i = index">
                <app-project-card [project]="projectList[i]"></app-project-card>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The code looks okay for me. Does you import **CommonModule** in the **app.module.ts** (imports) or your module (imports)?

Comment: Anyway, since you iterate the projectList, in your `app-project-card`, you can do as this `[project]="project"`instead of `[project]="projectList[i]"`.

Comment: I did import CommonModule in the app module. The weird thing is the error still occurs even when I remove the index and use your suggestion of `[project]="project"`

Comment: Anyway, can you create a Minimal Reproducible Example on [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com) for debugging purposes?